# Adding description into TextBoxes within an Excel VBA form that dissapears once user starts typing inside it

Tags: vba, excel, userform

We have a userform with multiple textboxes and we would like to build something similar to the link image below, in terms of showing what the user should input in each text box:

http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/426_formsBestPractices/comments.png

The "default" text would disappear once the user starts typing (as opposed than once the user "lands" cursor within the textbox.

Also, if nothing gets entered within the textbox the default text would not be submitted and a blank would be used.

Can this be done?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I ask why you want the default text to dissapear once a user changes the text and not once they enter the textbox?

This is not what most users will expect, I think it will be slightly confusing for some and wouldn't recommend it.  The user will most likely try and delete the old text before typing their new text creating extra work.

I would use something like this:

```
Const sNameDefault As String = "Your Name Here"
Const sEmailDefault As String = "Your Email Here"

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = sNameDefault
    Me.TextBox2.Text = sEmailDefault

    CommandButton1.SetFocus
End Sub

'// TextBox1 - Name
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    With Me.TextBox1
        If .Text = sNameDefault Then .Text = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    With Me.TextBox1
        If .Text = vbNullString Then .Text = sNameDefault
    End With
End Sub

'// TextBox2 - Email
Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    With Me.TextBox2
        If .Text = sEmailDefault Then .Text = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    With Me.TextBox2
        If .Text = vbNullString Then .Text = sEmailDefault
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sName As String, sEmail As String

    '// Get Name
    If Me.TextBox1.Text = sNameDefault Then
        sName = vbNullString
    Else
        sName = Me.TextBox1.Text
    End If

    '//  Get Email
    If Me.TextBox2.Text = sEmailDefault Then
        sEmail = vbNullString
    Else
        sEmail = Me.TextBox2.Text
    End If

    MsgBox ("Your Name: " & sName & vbNewLine & " Your Email:" & sEmail)

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The above example is simply a userform with two textbox's and a commandbutton.  Clicking inside the textbox will clear the default text.  If the user enters nothing clicking another textbox or control will cause the default text to be added back.  Once the command button is clicked the code will return blank if the default text remains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply above,... i guess it makes sense that it should dissapear once the user clicks in the box. Let me give it a go.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible :)

I have created a sample for you. You can download it from here.

http://wikisend.com/download/143478/Sample.xlsm

The trick is to create 2 similar TextBoxes and hide the 'original' one behind the dummy TextBox ("Which has the default text")

When you start typing in the dummy, the text will actually be typed in the textbox which is hidden.

And when you are pulling values, simply pull the values from the 2nd text box so the default data is not considered :)

Hope this helps.

**Code Used**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.SelStart = 0
    TextBox1.SelLength = Len(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox TextBox2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.Visible = False
    With TextBox2
        .Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "Please enter your name", "")
        .Visible = True
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Len(TextBox2.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```